# multiple options for php redirect based on current web page

Tags: php, redirect

I have multiple submission forms on a site I'm building. When a user submits the form I wish them to stay on the current page that they are on rather then be redirected so that they can view the message alert..

So based on that I want the one php file to be able to accomplish this. I currently have the following which works when on the contact page form submission:

```
// sending the email
  $mail = new PHPMailer();  
  $mail->From = $to;  
  $mail->FromName = $data['name'];     
  $mail->Mailer = "mail";
  $mail->AddReplyTo($data['email']);
  $mail->AddAddress($to);
  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->Body = $body;
  $mail->Send();

  $data = array();
  $_SESSION['flash_success'] = 'Your message has been sent.';
  header('location: contact.php'); exit;
```

So as one can see the location is set to stay on the contact page (Which works great when a user submits on the contact page). But when on the index page where I also have a contact form the user is of course being redirecting to the contact page once they submit the form. I have experimented with if else statements but I am having no luck. Any ideas how I tackle this?

Thanks

Comment: So, in a nutshell, you want to display something on the same page without being redirected?

Comment: You could have normal form handling.  And augment them with AJAX form submissions, so if you have JS support, appear to never leave the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a hidden field in your form, that includes data about where they are filling the form in.  And if successful, redirect them back after the processing.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // Where the user came from.
    $from = isset($_POST['from']) ? $_POST['from'] : null;

    // Form processing here if no errors and all a success set the following boolean to true.
    $form_success = true;

    // Only redirect to allowed locations.
    $redirect_to = in_array($from, ['home.php', 'contact.php'])
        ? $from // May require full web path here.
        : null;

    if($form_success && $redirect_to) {
        // Redirect
        header('location:' . $redirect_to);
        exit;
    }
}
// Else display form with helpful feedback
```

Example form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type='hidden' name='from' value='contact.php'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to implement this but Im having no luck. I put in the full webpage urls in place of  ($from, ['home.php', 'contact.php']. Was this the correct places to try and change?

Comment: Perhaps you hadn't set the $form_success bool to true.  Yes that's the correct place to change.